# How to use Pinia in Vue 3 components correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

What is the correct way to use Pinia's store in Vue 3 components?

Option A

```
const fooStore = useFooStore();

function bar() {
  return fooStore.bar
}

const compProp = computed(() => fooStore.someProp)
```

Option B

```
function bar() {
  return useFooStore().bar
}

const compProp = computed(() => useFooStore().someProp())
```

Questions:

1. Is it any difference between these 2 ways of calling the store?
2. in the `Option A` – may I be sure that the values from the store are the latest?
3. Could it be that `Option B` is less performant?
4. What is the best approach?

Comment: The second option is not a good idea because the context is changed from default to the `bar` function. In option one, you can make the `someProp` field reactive, so you don't need the `computed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad practice to use Vue composables in arbitrary places, they are intended to be used directly in setup block, any other usage needs to be confirmed and depends on the implementation of a composable. Pinia store composables are known to not be affected by this limitation, it's possible to use them anywhere, as long as Pinia is initialized.

Pinia's `defineStore` creates store composables instead of store objects to get around circular dependencies and race conditions associated with them, this also provides a way to use custom Pinia instance. If `useFooStore` is used inside another store, it needs to be called directly in a place where it's used, e.g. inside action function. There is no such problem when `useFooStore` is used inside a component, i.e. in setup block or lifecycle hooks.

There's no practical difference between these options. Option A is preferable because 1 `useFooStore` call takes less characters and resources than many of them.